# Last Generated autoincremented Id

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, primary-key

I have tables of auction and product they both use key of Product_Auction table to create record
i am generating the auto incremented `PA_ID(attribute)` of `Product_Auction` in mvc using

```
@db.Product_Auction.Add(new Product_Auction { PA_ID=1 });
```

it automatically increment in able ignoring 1 i want to get last generated value(auto incremented identity value)  how can i get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first select all the records, sort them, and limit the record to 1

For example.

Oracle SQL

```
select ID from TABLE order by ID DESC WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

MSSQL

```
select top(1) ID from TABLE order by ID DESC
```

Comment: what if multiple user accessing data, data of one will be passed to other